# XCUITest Screenshot cannot find 'add' in scope

Tags: ios, xcode, screenshot, xcuitest

```
1. let fullScreenshot = XCUIScreen.main.screenshot()
2. let screenshot = XCTAttachment(screenshot: fullScreenshot)
3. screenshot.lifetime = .keepAlways
4. add(screenshot)
```

I am trying to get a screenshot for when a test fails.
Using the code above which I've seen many people use in tutorials, I am getting an error on line 4.
"Cannot find 'add' in scope'.

I am not sure what this means.

I am not sure what to expect as I've looked everywhere and not seen a suggestion.

Comment: The `add` function is a member `XCTActivity`, of which `XCTestCase` conforms to. Are you importing `XCTest`? Is your class of `XCTestCase` type? Please share the rest of your test class.